# regex to allow decimals, but no commas

Tags: regex, numbers

I need a regex expression that allows decimals but no commas.  Such as:
1200.00
or 
50.00
or
40
or
1
The expression is used in a validation to make sure people put in a price as a number, but no commas.  I currently have a regex that allows for commas, numbers, and decimals, but I cannot seem to get the commas out.

This is the current regex that I have which doesnt allow commas or decimals, but I want decimals in there

```
/^[0-9\ ]+$/,
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work: `^\d+(\.\d{2})?$`

This basically states the following:

- `^\d+`: Start from the beginning of the string (`^`) and match one or more digits (`\d+`).
- `(\.\d{2})?`: Match a period character (`\.`) followed by exactly 2 digits (`\d{2}`). The question mark denotes that the value within the brackets can either exist or not, meaning that it will match either 1 or 0 instances of the pattern.
- `$`: The string must end here.

Comment: @Rookieatthis: Glad it worked. I just added some more info to my answer since I forgot to add the bit about the string termination (`$`).

Answer (score 1):

To match the currency you can use this regex

```
^(?:[1-9]\d+|\d)(?:\.\d\d)?$
```

Comment: I am quite sure you wanted to disallow leading 0, but then you have a little mistake in your regex: `[0-9]` should be `[1-9]` ==> `^(?:[1-9]\d+|\d)(?:\.\d\d)?$`

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to escape the　regex `.` operator (which means match any character). Only guessing since you forgot an important piece of information in your question: the failing regexes you have already tried!

Answer (score 0):

Allow 0 or 1 dots, with only digits before and after...

```
/^\d*\.{0,1}\d*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

check double/integer type price. (cannot type comma and only type one decimal)

```
 r'^(?:[1-9]\d+|\d)(?:\.\d*)?$';
```

Comment: Please explain the specifics about what you are matching, code-only answers are unlikely to help future visitors. Without an explanation I for example can't tell the functional difference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10169158/8517948) .