# Allow only a single point in decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I modify this regular expression to allow numbers with just one point?

```
/[^0-9\.]/g
```

It currently allows:

- 0
- 0.13
- 0.13.1 (this should not be allowable)

Comment: There are so many similar questions linked on the right of this page. Didn't you see them when you were writing your question ?

Comment: You don't need to escape a dot in a character class

Comment: @dystroy, I did thorough search before posting, but none provided satisfiable answer. and none on the right point to what i am asking

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169147/regex-to-allow-decimals-but-no-commas?rq=1

Comment: Trying to find the duplicate, but [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734671/javascript-regular-expression-that-validates-one-at-begning-and-one-decima) is closed. Does it answer your question? Can you figure it out from the (pretty good) explanation there?

Comment: @dystroy, that either doesn't match with question I asked

Comment: @minitech thanks, that matches similar to what I asked for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your regex doesn't matches what you say it matches. You have used *negation* in character class, and that too without any quantifier. Currently it would match any non-digit character other than `.`.

For your requirement, you can use this regex:

```
/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

Comment: +1 as you got to the correct answer first (not the first answer, but I saw the edits) :)

Comment: @rps: No, the brackets and the spaces don’t belong.

Comment: @rps. Syntax is fine. But that doesn't do what you think. I suggest you to read on *Character Classes*.  A character class matches just a single character, from all the characters included in it. Also, meta-characters don't have any special meaning in character class. So, `[\d+]` doesn't matches 1 or more digits, but it matches either a `\d` or a `+`.

Comment: @rps. Yeah, now it will work fine. It is now equivalent to what I've written above. You can take out common patterns from pipe, and make rest uncommon pattern optional using `?` quantifier

Comment: @rps: Yep, that seems fine. The second `+` could be `*`, though, because (at least to JavaScript and most people, I think) `.5` is a valid number.

Comment: Doesn't work allows multiple digits after the decimal point, OP asked for ONE.

Answer (score 4):

Make the match a positive one:

```
/^\d*(\.\d+)?$/
```

Any number of digits, optionally followed by a point and at least one digit. But it’s not worth it to keep a negative match.

If you want to disallow an empty string (which the original regular expression wouldn’t do), you could do this:

```
/^(?=.)\d*(\.\d+)?$/
```

But you could also just check for an empty string, which looks better anyways.

Comment: This will even match an empty string.

Comment: @HamZa: But who knows.

Comment: Basically a poor question doesn't get a full answer. There should be a dup though ...

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should do `/^(\d*)\.{0,1}(\d){0,1}$/` OR `/^(\d*)\.?(\d){0,1}$/`

- `(\d*)` Represents number of digits before decimal.
- `\.` followed by `{0,1}` OR `?` will make sure that there is only one dot.
- `(\d){0,1}` Allows only one digit after decimal.

Comment: You don't need to add the 0, you can just do {1}.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following regex ^[-+]?\d*.?\d*$

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
/^(\d*)(\.\d*)?$/g
```

Comment: The matching groups are useless

Comment: not if you want to manually check for them... who knows what his use case is

Comment: Making `\d*` optional also doesn’t do anything, this allows the empty string, this allows a single dot. But who knows.

Comment: modified it so that last expression will only optionally find a . and a set of numbers as an optional single group

Answer (score -1):

Try,

```
(value.match(/^\d+([.]\d{0,1})?$/))
```

Comment: `[.]` → `\.`; `{0,1}` → `?`; `value.match(x)` → `x.test(value)`