# javascript match Regex for numbers and only dot character

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, decimal, special-characters

I need to match Regex for an input text. It should allow only numbers and only one dot.

Below is my pattren.

```
(?!\s)[0-9\.\1]{0,}
```

This is allowing only numbers and allowing multiple dots. How to write so that it should allow only one dot?

Bascially when i enter decimal, i need to round off to whole number.

Comment: /^\d+(\.\d+)?$/ answer obtained from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149155/allow-only-a-single-point-in-decimal-numbers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple regular expression for a decimal with a precision of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2)

Comment: Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811031/decimal-or-numeric-values-in-regular-expression-validation/39399503#39399503)

Answer (score 1):

In case you dont mind accepting just a point, this should do it

```
\d*\.\d*
```

Otherwise, the more complete answer could look like this:

```
\d*\.\d+)|(\d+\.\d*)
```

Comment: This is incorrect as it will match even if I put just '.' in my string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to select your integer and fractional parts than add 1 to your integer part depending to your fractional part:

Regex: `^(\d+)\.(\d+)$`

In use:

```js
function roundOff(str) {
  return str.replace(/^(\d+)\.(\d+)$/g, ($0, $1, $2) => $2.split('')[0] >= 5 ? parseInt($1) + 1 : parseInt($2)); 
}

var str1 = roundOff('123.123') 
console.log(str1); // 123

var str2 = roundOff('123.567')
console.log(str2); // 124
```

Comment: But how do i restrict multiple dots?

Comment: @Matarishvan It's already doing it. This regex will only match strings which contains a single dot between digits. If your string has multiple dots than this regex will not match at all.

Comment: This is allowing multiple dots. Its failing

Comment: Could you edit my regex linked in my previous comment adding a case where multiple dots are matched? I'll really appreciate that. [link is here again](https://regex101.com/r/uwmcvJ/1)